# How to send imputed data from R script to another script

Tags: r, dataframe

I have make a script that imputes the missing data (NA) in the file but i want to send this imputed data to another R.script from this script
my_code:

```
library(randomForest) #We need to load the “randomForest” package in order to use its functions
path.name = "D:/Courses/Bioinformatics Diploma/Statistical Analysis and Visualization/Assignments/Assignment 1/Assignment_01_Data.csv"
GE_Data_Modification = read.table(path.name, sep = ',', header = T, row.names = 1)
GE_Data_Modification = as.data.frame(t(GE_Data_Modification)) #Transposed data to compute column median
GE_Data_Modification = na.roughfix(GE_Data_Modification)#Impute the data through the median of columns
GE_Data_Modification = as.data.frame(t(GE_Data_Modification)) #Return to the original layout of the data
```

I want to send the results to another script called GE_Data_Normalization.R

Comment: You can convert the object to `.RData`,`save` and `load` it in other script

Comment: no i do not want to load it in the other script i want to write a code at the end of the first script that can send the imputed data from the first script to the second one

Comment: Your question is not very clear as it can be interpreted as writing the 'GE_Data_Modification' to directory and then read the data from the second script or just source the first script into second.  It all depends upon whether you are running this in sequentiall order with the second or not

Comment: can I send the results of the first script to another one by using source function in the first script?

Comment: I am not folllowing why you can't call the source in second script.  source load the script1 and executes the commands.  If you already executed those commands in script1, you could use `save` and `load` as `.RData`

Comment: ok I will try source in the second file, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `source` the first script to second script by placing the below line at the top of the second script

```
#GE_Data_Normalization.R
source("path/to/your/firstscript.R")
message("Number of rows of GE_Data_Modification")
message(nrow(GE_Data_Modification))
# code start from second script
....
...
```